# Insert Counts for SaveAsTable and Insert INTO

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, hive, hiveql

I have a Scala code that I run in spark-shell to extract data from json files and load first in a HIVE staging table and then extract data from staging and load into the final main table in HIVE.

I use the following commands:

```
//read json to DF
  val df = hiveContext.read.schema(schema1).json(file)
//DF to Staging
  df.write.mode("append").saveAsTable("stg")
//Staging to Final
  hiveContext.sql("insert into final select distinct columns from stg left outer join final on stg.id = final.id where stg.id is not null and final.id is null")
```

I want to be able to understand the counts of records read/written at every stage.
For json to DF, I understand that I can do **df.count()** but how about the remaining two stages. How do I get the count of saveAsTable and Insert into statements?

Comment: run `select count(*)` on `stg` and `final`?

Comment: Thanks but I think this will give me total number of records in stg and final and not just the ones I inserted during my job run. I need the counts inserted at each step during every run of the script.